# Strange behaviour: "\listoffigures" shown at very first page

Tags: floats, captions

I have some figures like the following

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, keepaspectratio=true]{img/test_example.png}
\caption{Auszug aus dem Integritätstest}
\label{Integritätstest}
\end{figure}
```

the figure itself is rendered propperly and also the list of figures, but somehow all captions are printed at the very beginning of my document. But there is no \listoffigures command or anything like this. I'm bit new to LaTeX, so I don't now what kind of information is important to analyze this problem. Here my main file with used packages and that stuff, hope it helps.

```
\documentclass[ a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openany, parskip, final, 11pt, appendixprefix, chapterprefix ]{scrreprt}
%-------------------%
% include packages  %
%-------------------%
\usepackage[twoside,width=14cm, height=24cm,right=3.25cm, left=2.5cm]{geometry} %zweiseitig
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{mdwlist}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}   %including images
\usepackage{fancyhdr}   %for editiable headers and footers
\usepackage{setspace}   %for 1,5times row space
\usepackage[colorlinks,pdfpagelabels,pdfstartview = FitH,bookmarksopen = true,bookmarksnumbered = true,linkcolor = black,plainpages = false,hypertexnames = false,citecolor = black, linkcolor=black, menucolor=black, pagecolor=black, urlcolor=black] {hyperref}  
\usepackage{multirow}   %linebreak in Table
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{colortbl}   %colorTables
\usepackage{framed}   %begin{framed}
\usepackage{longtable} %begin{longtable}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage[square]{natbib}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\include{helpers/include-syntax-php}    % PHP Syntax-Highlighting
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}

%------------------%
% config document  %
%------------------%

\pdfcompresslevel0
\lstset{%
basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize\color{black},
commentstyle = \ttfamily\color{gray},
keywordstyle=\ttfamily\color{blue},
stringstyle=\color{red},
showspaces=false,               % show spaces adding particular underscores
showstringspaces=false, 
frame=single
}

% spaces
\parskip 5pt           % sets spacing between paragraphs
\parindent 0pt  
%\vspace*{2.3\baselineskip} = ORIGINAL 
\renewcommand*{\chapterheadstartvskip}{\vspace*{0\baselineskip}}

%headers/footers
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesubsection\ #1}}
\lhead[ \leftmark   ]{\textbf{\paperTitle}}
\rhead[\textbf{\workingTitle}]{\leftmark}
\lfoot[\thepage    ]{\scriptsize \textcopyright\the\year, \paperAuthor}
\cfoot[]{}
\rfoot[\scriptsize \textcopyright\the\year, \paperAuthor]{\thepage}

%macros
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
 %\newcommand{\cbox}{\includegraphics[width=0.2cm]{material/cbox.png} \ }
\definecolor{Gray}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.90}
 %\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}  %kleineres TOC
\newcommand{\arr}{$ \Longrightarrow$}

\makeindex  %start index

\date{\today}
\onehalfspacing

\setlength{\epigraphwidth}{.8\textwidth}

%-----------------%
% start document  %
%-----------------%

\begin{document}
 %includes...
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out, that the `\label{}` command is responsible for this strange behaviour. But I don't know why. Removing it solves the Problem.

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Could you please compose a little *complete* MWE illustrating the odd behaviour mentioned and add it to your question?